# Expression for finding an index in an array

Tags: ada, ada2012, spark-2014

How can I find the first character in a string that is the space character and return its index, with a single expression that can be used as part of `Contract_Cases`?

For example, if the string is:

```vhdl
Input : constant String := "abc def";
```

then the expression should return `4`.

Comment: The first non-space character in that string has index 1. Also, it’d be more idiomatic to omit the `(1 .. 7)` and let the compiler figure it out!

Comment: @SimonWright, thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question originally asked for the first **non-blank** character in the string, for which you need `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index_Non_Blank` ([ARM A.4.3(12)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-3.html#p12) and [(61)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-3.html#p61)).

As amended (the first **blank** character in the string), use `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index` - see the OP’s comment below.

Comment: Thanks, this works! My question was wrong though (I'm looking for the first space, not non-space), so in this case it looks like I can use `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index` ([ARM A.4.3(8.1/2)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-3.html#I5809) and [(56.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-3.html#p56.1)).